# How to define the regex for a string to separete key,value pair

Tags: groovy

I am trying to divide a string into key:value pair in groovy but since my key has multiple values i am not able to acheieve the right result . It just prints the first value

I am trying below

```
def keyValueString = "key1:value1,value2,key2:value1,value2,value3,key3:value1"

def regex = /([^:,]+):((?:[^:,]+(?:,(?![:]))?)+)/

def matcher = keyValueString =~ regex


matcher.each { match ->
    def key = match[1]
    def value = match[2]

    println key 
    println value 

}
```

when i print the key and value i only don't get the right results. I want to separate each key,value pair like

```
key1:value1,value2
key2:value1,value2
key3:value1
```

is there another way to do this in groovy ?

Comment: The problem here is that the key-value sets are not clearly demarcated. It is a bad data format. The best way to address this is upstream at the source of the string if you can. Assuming that your data is not literally called "key" and "value", makes it even harder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could maybe use this:

```
def keyValueString = "key1:value1,value2,key2:value1,value2,value3,key3:value1"

def regex = /((.+?):([^:]+)(?:,|$))/

def matcher = keyValueString =~ regex

matcher.each { match ->
    println "${match[2]} maps to ${match[3]}"
}
```

Which prints:

```
key1 maps to value1,value2
key2 maps to value1,value2,value3
key3 maps to value1
```

Comment: Thank you. This did the trick and i got the key and values from above and was able to process them further as required.